# How to get requested Url before Login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Some Controller-Actions in my page are decorated with the `[Authorize]` attribute. The forward to the Login page works perfect, but after successful login, I want to forward to the requested url. With `Request.UrlReferrer`, I get the url where I come from, but how can I get the requested action (which requires the login)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Login()` action takes a string parameter called `returnUrl` which will be used when redirecting from the login.

You can add the returnUrl to the ViewBag and return a view.

For Eg:

```
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
     ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
     return View();
}
```

The target action uses the posted data to authenticate the user and log in the user using FormsAuthentication. It then redirects the user back to the returnUrl.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (//Validation Check)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
        return Redirect(returnUrl); // Redirect to referer
    }

    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
    return View(model);
}
```